# How can I avoid frequent int/float/double casts when developing an XNA application?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, xna, windows-phone-7.1

I'm making a simple 2D game for Windows Phone 7 (Mango) using the XNA Framework.

I've made the following observations:

- Most of the drawing operations accept `float`s
- `SpriteBatch.Draw` accepts a `Rectangle` which uses `int`s
- The `Math` class accepts `double`s as parameters and also returns `double`s

So my code is full of typecasts between `int`s, `float`s and `double`s. That's a hell a lot of typecasts.

Is there any way I can get rid of them or I should just not care about this?

Also, do these typecasts present a measurable performance loss?

Comment: If possible use the `MathHelper` XNA class. It has some methods and constants that are floats. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.mathhelper%28v=XNAGameStudio.40%29.aspx

Comment: Hm, that's very nice! :) Only things missing are trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed this too but unless you notice any speed decrease, it could be considered a micro-optimization. Converting between `float` and `int` is relatively expensive whereas converting between `float` and `double` is cheap. So wherever you don't need to perform a `float` to `int` conversion, you can avoid it. Type casting is generally cheaper than actual conversion (e.g. using `Convert.ToInt32`).
 However, all of this is unlikely to be a bottleneck unless you're performing it many times. Also, from [this post](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/90687/543238.aspx):

> - float, double and int multiplications have the same performance ==> use the right type of number for your app, no worries
> - the phone is 4x to 10x slower than the PC I use to develop my apps ==> test with a real phone, don't trust your PC for math operations
> - divisions are up to 8x slower than multiplications! ==> don't use divisions, e.g. try to use 1/a then multiply

Unofficial numbers, but I think the last one is quite an accepted method. Also, doubles are often thought to be slower than floats, but this comes down to the system it's running on. AFAIK, Windows Phone is optimized to use `doubles`, which would explain the `Math` class accepting those.

All in all, I'd say it's quite common to see casting occur quite a bit with the XNA framework. Of course, it should be avoided whenever possible, but it's unlikely to be the source of bottlenecks for games unless you need to perform it often, in which case other areas may be easier to optimize (or a redesign of the game structure might be required).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :) I'm new to XNA and somehow I was feeling "guilty" by all those typecasts. And yeah, I'm testing on an actual phone (A Nokia Lumia 800), and I don't see any performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about the Rectangle conversion, there are overloads that take Vector2's instead, which are float-based:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433988.aspx

Note the source (texture) is still a rectangle but this is typically a static (not C# keyword `static` but unchanging, undynamic) thing.

Comment: I know there is such an overload, but honestly the overload that takes a Rectangle is a lot more convenient to use most of the time. :)

Comment: Not disagreeing, but that is technically one way to avoid them.